# Class.forName doesn't find a loaded class

Tags: java, jvm

I am experimenting with some cheats made for a Java game. A specific cheat blew my mind. I noticed that all the names of the classes it loads start with an exclamation mark so I decided to try and get one of those classes by name. The cheat crashes if you forget to delete the settings file it creates so I got the name of one of them - "!M". I decided that I'd inject a jar file in the game myself and experiment with that class. I created a JAR loader in C and the JAR itself. I used Cheat Engine to verify that the class itself is loaded in the JVM. I created a simple JAR which called this code upon injection:

```
try {
    Class<?> cheatClass = Class.forName("!M");
    showMSGBox(cheatClass.getName());
    showMSGBox(cheatClass.getSuperclass().getName());
} catch (Exception ex) {
    showMSGBox(ex.toString());
}
```

Where showMSGBox(string) simply shows a JOptionPane. When I injected the JAR in the game using the loader I made, I was granted with an error which stated that there is no such a class. I opened Cheat Engine again and saw the class is still there. Any ideas why this could happen and what causes it?

Comment: `Class.forName(String)` uses the caller’s class loader. Since your code has been loaded by a custom loader, it will attempt to load the class through that custom loader. If it hasn’t a class of that name in its scope, that operation fails.

Comment: My loader utilizes the main classloader of the game, though. I'll try and find which classloader the cheat uses and attempt to load it through it, thank you for the accurate answer.

Comment: @Holger will creating a JAR agent instead of injecting the JAR through C help me find the class, because I know that Agents can access all classes?

Comment: You mean searching via [`getAllLoadedClasses()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/Instrumentation.html#getAllLoadedClasses--)? That may work, but be aware that there might be more than one class with the same name, defined by different loaders. It looks like you’re talking about a software actively trying to make things harder for you, so it might exploit this possibility…

Comment: The only classes that have a name starting with an exclamation mark in the game are the cheat's classes and I haven't seen another class which has that exact name.